# Health check in aws route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Q1.)While creating a record using failover-policy in route53-hosted-zone :

What is the difference between "evaluate-target-health" and "associate-health-check" ?

Q2.)Does route53 perform health check for EACH dns-request it receives ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for your 1st question is already given by John Hanley. The answer for your 2nd question is NO.

According to [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-how-route-53-chooses-records.html),

> "If you associated a health check with a non-alias record, Route 53 checks the current status of the health check.
>
> Route 53 periodically checks the health of the endpoint that is specified in a health check; it doesn't perform the health check when the DNS query arrives."

I hope that answers your question :)

Answer (score 3):

Both basically do the same thing. The key difference is that Evaluate Target Health is used with ALIAS records, e.g. a load balancer DNS endpoint and Associate with Health Check is used with A records, e.g. a web server's static IP address.

Evaluate Target Health does not use a health check that you create. Associate with Health Check uses a health check that you create.

Another way to compare the differences. Use Evaluate Target Health for an AWS service that manages its health status. Use Associate Health check for a service that you control and determine its health status thru your own health check.